# BFG Repo cleaner - how to remove the secrets history from tags

Tags: github, bfg-repo-cleaner

I am following the steps from below link to remove the secrets from git history.

https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

But the history is not getting removed from the tags. Could you please help on how to remove the history from tags?

Comment: Tags are just pointers to commits. What BFG command line parameters are you using?

Comment: git push --force
(or)
git push origin --force --tags

But --tags are not allowed in --mirror

Comment: That's the **Git** command line. What is the **BFG** command line you ran?

Answer (score 0):

You must start cloning the repo with `--mirror`, this way git will clone all refs, **including branches and tags**. Then you run the tool to clean all refs out. When you push, all cleaned refs are going to be pushed back.

As per the [documentation](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#usage):

> First clone a fresh copy of your repo, using the --mirror flag:

```
$ git clone --mirror git://example.com/some-big-repo.git
```

> This is a bare repo, which means your normal files won't be visible,
> but it is a full copy of the Git database of your repository, and at
> this point you should make a backup of it to ensure you don't lose
> anything.